# How to use Retain and Release in IOS Application?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, retain, xcode5.1

I am working on an iOS application.When i am using flicker API's in my application i am getting semantic issues that i can't use the libraries bcoz os release and retain is used in the library.I am working on XCODE 5.1?
Please help me that how can i use such library in my Application?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6658549/2919739

Answer (score 0):

Select the project in the sidebar > Build Phases > Compile Sources

Add the flag `-fno-objc-arc` to the files in question.

Comment: i am adding .h and .m files in project in compile sources and then run Xcode ,but getting error..i am not getting where i have to add the flag -fno-objc-arc in the project..please help me out ?

Comment: If you double click on the .m file (which should be shown in the Compile Sources list if added to the project), you can enter the flag in the popup.